# Loop through all check boxed and add specific slides to array

Tags: vba, if-statement, checkbox, foreach, powerpoint

I would like to make an array (Set Selected_slds = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range) of slides. The slides are to be part of an array that can be selected from a number of Check boxes.  So, the idea of the code I would like to write is:

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim list_of_slides As Array
Dim Selected_slds As SlideRange


For k = 1 To Count(CheckBoxs)
    If CheckBox(k) = True Then
        add.slide(k) to list_of_slides
    End If
Next

Set Selected_slds = list_of_slides
```

The above is part of a longer code, where Selected_slds is used.

What I have done so far is this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim k As Integer

' Look at each shape on each slide in the active pres
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        ' Is the shape a control?
        If oSh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            ' Is it a checkbox?
            If InStr(UCase(oSh.OLEFormat.ProgID), "FORMS.CHECKBOX") > 0 Then
                ' BINGO, found what we're after, so ...
                If oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
                    MsgBox "Checked"
                ElseIf oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = False Then
                    MsgBox "Uncheked"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ' Shape
Next ' Slide
```

End Sub

Which works, but I am not sure what to do, to get it to do what I am looking for. It is coded in power point.

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do?  You don't seem to have explained that.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg  I would like the code to create a list (Set Selected_slds = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range) of certain slides. The slides should be choosen from which check box are marked. 
lthorst is typing...
lthorst: So, for example, if checkBox1 = TRUE, then it should add slide 1 into the list. If CheckBox2 = TRUE it should add slide 4, 5, and 7 to the list. And so on.